# Hibernate failed to execute query afte 1 day

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat6, c3p0

I am getting following error in my web application after one day. I have dont lot of search on it for couldn't fix this problem yet. Can anybody help me out?

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was59461 milliseconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 59461 milliseconds ago, which  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1932)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1761)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1912)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1778)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3251)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: Your problem is exactly the same as in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565143/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operati/7621207#7621207

Answer (score 10):

You need to configure hibernate to execute dummy query so that your connection stays alive .

```
<!--connection pool--> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxActive">10</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.whenExhaustedAction">1</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWait">20000</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property> 

<!-- prepared statement cache--> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxActive">10</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.whenExhaustedAction">1</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxWait">20000</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxIdle">10</property> 

<!-- optional query to validate pooled connections:--> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery">select 1</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow">true</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn">true</property>
```

Comment: who will execute dummy query according to your configs? or validationQuery is executed with specific interval?

Comment: @Maksym usually the underlying connection pooling subsystem will configure itself and validate the connection (either periodically or on borrow or depending on your config)

Answer (score 0):

If You use c3p0 connection pool set `testConnectionOnCheckout=true` and `idle_test_period=30` it means that connection will be checked in background in every 30 sec.

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="30"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="60"/>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="30" /> <!-- seconds -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
```

**preferredTestQuery** values :

```
With MySQL: SELECT 1
With Oracle: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
With Ms SQL Server: SELECT 1
```

To test your configuration et Your **logger** to debug :

```
<logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.mchange">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```