# spring boot on remote - MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Localy spring boot app works but on remote server I got:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException",   "message": "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   No operations allowed after connection closed.; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   No operations allowed after connection closed.

All settings are the same and application connects to the same database.

I added the following settings and now it is working:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_size 2000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.min_size 100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.timeout 5000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_statements 1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period 3000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment 2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.validate false
```

What is the reason occurrence of this error? 
What caused that spring boot app stopped working?

Comment: For starters you shouldn't be using the hibernate internal connection pool, but configure a proper connection pool yourself. Also post the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565143/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operati

Comment: add more details. actual code and config