# Updating database record in Java by using executeUpdate() function

Tags: java, mysql, database, record

I'm trying to update record in mysql database using java.
This is my code:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
sql = "update users set email='" + email1.getText() + "' WHERE fullname='" + user1 + "'";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
stmt.close();
con.close();
```

I'm getting this error:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed.

Comment: works if you do other query?

Comment: check if your db server is up and running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565143/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operati)

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Thanks for help...